# Raise event to ListView from List ItemView

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a custom ItemView that I am trying to implement and I want to raise event back to ListView that is a parent. How do I go about doing that?

For example my ItemView has.  How do I get the ListView owner to invoke event?

```
public partial class MyItemView : ContentView, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
}
```

Comment: I'd probably use MessagingCenter instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the ListView from the item of ListView by iterating View's parent till we get the ListView.

```
public partial class MyItemView : ContentView, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    ListView listView;

    protected override void LayoutChildren(double x, double y, double width, double height)
    {
        base.LayoutChildren(x, y, width, height);

        Element list = this;

        while(list.GetType() != typeof(ListView))
        {
            list = list.Parent;
        }

        listView = list as ListView;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll try this.  Is it wrong to do in LayoutChanged event     private void MyItemView_LayoutChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     listView = this.Parent.Parent as MyListView;
    }